# iAd Banner implementation on Game Over Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, ads

So I have a game that has a game over class. I also have an iAd banner at the bottom of the screen, but it stays there for the entire length of the game. I want the banner to appear when the game ends, and disappear when the user presses the restart game button.

In my `RootViewController.mm` I have the following code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:adView]; 
}
```

How would I go about only displaying an iAd banner when the game ends?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you would like to delete this, please flag for moderator attention using a custom moderator flag and explain why you think it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bit of code:

When your game ends: `[self showiAdBanner];`

When your game begins: `[self hideiAdBanner];`

If you use this code, you'll want to replace this:

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

with this:

```
[self showiAdBanner];
```

Two methods to show iad and hide iad:

```
- (void)showiAdBanner {
    if( !_adView ) { // only add to view if it's not already there
        _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)]; //initialize it
        _adView.delegate = self; // set delegate
    }
    _adView.hidden = NO; //reveal it
    _bannerIsVisible = YES; //set bool to yes
}

- (void)hideiAdBanner {
   _adView.hidden = YES; //hide it
   _bannerIsVisible = NO; // set bool to no
}
```

Remember to add this part as well:

```
@interface RootViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@end
```

If you want to get fancy, instead of hiding it, you can animate/fade it out.

Comment: Im getting a whole bunch of undeclared identifiers

Comment: use of undeclared identifier "_adView", "_bannerIsVisible", etc.

Comment: Also, i changed the code up, I've edited OP to show the new code

Comment: Ah I see. Try adding two properties up top. I'll edit my post to show you what i mean

Comment: It doesn't look like `_bannerIsVisible` is actually being used anywhere. And what happens when the ad is not filled and you present it anyways? In the `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods you should set its `alpha` property accordingly to avoid showing an empty banner.

Comment: OP edited his post and removed the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [Shared iAd Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011212-CH1-TNTAG3) in your `AppDelegate` and then present the `ADBannerView` on which ever `ViewController` you like. This implementation takes into account that an `ADBannerView` will not always receive an ad from the iAd network. The `ADBannerView`'s `alpha` property is set depending on whether it receives an ad or not using the `ADBannerView`'s delegate methods. This way, you can just display and hide the `ADBannerView` when the game ends and when you reset it knowing that the `ADBannerView` will only be visible if it has an ad to present.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import iAd; // Import iAd

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate> // Include delegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *adView;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Create our one ADBannerView
    _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]init];
    // Set delegate and hide banner initially
    _adView.delegate = self;
    _adView.hidden = YES;
    return YES;
}

// iAd delegate methods
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");
    _adView.alpha = 1.0;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@",error);
    _adView.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create reference to our app delegate
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // Position
    appDelegate.adView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height - appDelegate.adView.frame.size.height / 2);
    // Add to view
    [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.adView];

    // I'm just calling the gameOver function for example
    // You should add the contents of the function to something more suitable
    [self gameOver];
}

-(void)gameOver {
    // Unhide the ADBannerView in which ever function is called first in the gameover view
    // I'm guessing you have a UIButton that this would work in
    appDelegate.adView.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)gameReset {
    // When you reset the game hide the ADBannerView
    // I'm guessing you have a UIButton that this would work in also
    appDelegate.adView.hidden = YES;
}
```